# The Bee's Knees or Molten Fury vs Wall of Flesh?

Tags: terraria

I have restarted my Terraria, and beaten all the bosses before the Wall Of Flesh, but I am having trouble deciding which weapon is better to use against it. I am choosing between [The Bee's Knees](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Bee's_Knees) or [Molten Fury](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Molten_Fury).

I also have no idea where my glowing mushroom biome is.

So which one is better to use against the Wall of Flesh; The Bee's Knees or Molten Fury?

Comment: I am on expert mode if anyone is wondering.

Comment: Medusa is found in marble caves, and you will have both marble caves and glowing mushroom biomes regardless of your world size. You just haven't found them yet.

Comment: @TheDestroyer That medusa's head question is unrelated to your otyher question, it's better to post that as a separate question.

Comment: Ok i will next time

Comment: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hellwing_Bow is where it's at. Would highly recommend trying to get one.

Answer (score 4):

The Bee's Knees is highly recommended against the Wall of Flesh.

Firstly the initial damage is about the same, slightly higher for the Molten Fury, with one extra damage and the On Fire! debuff, so there isn't too much difference with just the initial shot.

However the Bees Knees is strong especially against the Wall of Flesh because after it hits it's an enemy it will pierce it and the bees can cause damage to whatever's behind it. This is perfect for the Wall of Flesh because it can be hard to cause damage to the Wall as The Hungry are in the way, making it difficult. But with The Bee's Knees, you can do damage to the Wall while still taking out the Hungry.

Also another bonus of the Bee's Knees is that if you miss, which is quite easy to do when you're running for your life from a giant wall of flesh, the Bee's Knees 'arrow' can ricochet off the wall (breaking into five separate bees like when it pierces a target) and come back and possibly do damage again. This is far superior to the Molten Fury, because if you miss with that you do zero damage, and you'll likely miss many times during this fight.

Comment: Thanks for answering! This will help me tremendously when trying to fight the wall of flesh!

Comment: @TheDestroyer no worries! Good luck, it's a tough fight, just make sure you set up the arena properly and large enough and enough ammo and you'll be okay! The minishark with meteor ammo is also recommended because of similar reasons to the above answer.

Comment: This is assuming you are using wooden arrows in both cases. The bees knees will always be outperformed by the molten fury when you use any other arrowtype.

Comment: Yes I am using both of the suggested items

Comment: @Arperum I don't think so, Jester's arrows and Unholy arrows are potentially good, as they can pierce but jester's cost fallen stars to make so it's unlikely you'll have enough and unholy arrows are only 8 dmg more than the bee's knees, each bee does 1-4 damage too so it's essentially the same damage, more damage if you have the hive pack even more damage, plus the bees knees can ricochet, and the bees are homing, so I still think the bee's knees is going to far out dps the molten fury. Also I think the range of unholy arrows is quite low compared to jesters and the bee arrow

Comment: Ok I will bring wooden arrows